# But he can count you off Saxon and Norman shrines till daylight,

Tags: meaning

> '"Ay," said De Aquila, all in a muse. "That man broke Harold of Norway
>   at Stamford Bridge, and came near to breaking us at Santlache--all
>   within one month."
>
> '"But how did he come alive from Santlache fight?" asked the King.
>   "Ask him! Hast thou heard it, Rahere?" "Never. He says he has been
>   stoned too often for telling the tale. **But he can count you off
>   Saxon and Norman shrines till daylight**," said Rahere and the old man
>   nodded proudly

This is from "The Tree of Justice" in "Rewars and Fairies" by Kipling.
http://www.telelib.com/authors/K/KiplingRudyard/prose/RewardsFaries/treejustice.html

I do not understand the meaning below.
But he can count you off Saxon and Norman shrines till daylight,"

I am glad if somebody kindly teach me.

Comment: He can spend the entire night listing Saxon and Norman shrines (of saints) -- presumably shrines he has visited.

Comment: StoneyB, than you so much for your comment!!